# Uncaught Error: TypeError: Object #<Storage> has no method 'put'

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to put some information in HTML5 LocalStorage, however, I am presented with the error "Object # has no method 'put'" on the following code:

```
window.localStorage.put('thing1', thing1);
window.localStorage.put('thing2', thing2);
window.localStorage.put('json', JSON.stringify(json));
```

At the beginning of the script I've checked if localstorage exists. Do I not need to specify the window object before localStorage?

Comment: Try [`localStorage.setItem` instead](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: Thanks, figured this out as soon as I posted my question. :p

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` uses `localStorage.setItem`, not `localStorage.put`.